# HoloLens companion map

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, hololens

I am implementing a "companion map" for a HoloLens application using Unity and Visual Studio. My vision is for a small rectangular map to be affixed to the bottom right of the HoloLens view, and to follow the HoloLens user as they move about, much like the display of a video game.

At the moment my "map" is a .jpeg made into a material and put on an upright plane. Is there a way for me to affix the plane such that it is always in the bottom right of the user's view, as opposed to being fixed in the 3D space that the user moves through?

Answer (score 0):

The [`Orbital Solver`](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Solver.html#orbital) in MRTK can implement this idea without even writing any code. It can lock the map to a specified position and offset it from the player.

To use it what you need to do is:

1. Add `Orbital` Script Component to your companion map.
2. Modify the `Local Offset` and `World Offset` properties to keep the map in the bottom right of the user's view.
3. Modify the `Orientation Type` as `Face Tracked Object`.

Besides, the [SolverExamples](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_development/Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.Examples/Demos/Solvers/Scenes/SolverExamples.unity) scene provided by the mrtkv2 SDK is an excellent outset to become familiar with `Solver` components

Comment: When I attempt to add the Orbital script component to my companion map I get an error saying "Can't add script behaviour ScreenSpaceMousePointer. The script needs to derive from MonoBehaviour!" Not sure how to get around this...